# Am I being unreasonable with my company which is trying to change my commuting shortly after hiring me?

Tags: united-states, new-job, termination, telecommute, commute

I was just hired for my first full-time position since graduating from University. The location is 15 minutes away from my parent’s house, and I just moved back in with them from college to accept/commute to this office. My written offer letter stated that I would be reporting to my local office.

Not even two weeks into my employment, a few Chiefs asked my boss if he would be ok with them “borrowing” me for a project, which would involve commuting 50 miles from my home for the next two months.

I told them, quite frankly, that I wasn’t hired to work at their new office, and I wouldn’t be able to commute there every day. I mentioned that I’d be able to commute once a week and work remotely from the original office, and that I would do everything necessary to overcome the learning curve and issues that come with telecommuting.

Am I being unreasonable, and is this something they can terminate me for?

Comment: What country are you in, and what does your employment contact say about your place of work?

Comment: Why don't you ask to do the normal commute, then they can arrange transport for 50 miles there and back before days end. Thats normal in my locale. eg If you start at 8am they can then drive you around all day if they want so long as you're back to clock out at 5pm. An alternative to is to make the commute time part of your working hours and get a travel allowance.

Comment: Did they start by telling you to do this, or rather asked you whether / how could you accommodate this?

Comment: @Nathan, After you told the company that, what have been the responses of the company,  your current manager, the team that wants to borrow you, or Human Resources, etc...  so far ? Have they proposed any compromising options that may work for both you and them ?

Comment: I assume this is an abstract question? Because currently most countries still have the obligatory remote working, unless the character of the work makes remote working impossible, which seems not to be a case

Comment: In Germany it is (officially) considered  reasonable to commute for up to 2 hours (one direction). The distance you can cover also relates to your mode of transport. Few people do, but they exist.

Comment: Need to include country on this as the rules are totally different depending on the country ...

Comment: @DanubianSailor working from home requirements vary a lot between countries, and are starting to be removed in some places.  It's also perfectly possible that the OP has a role that needs them to be physically present to some extent, at least some of the time.  Location really matters

Comment: @Erik whose responsibility is that commute? Here in the UK it's generally up to the employee, but employment law may address changes in terms of employment like a significant change of location.  2 hours is a lot to do twice a day.  My 1.5 is pushing it with anything approaching a family life

Comment: @ChrisH the commute is responsibility of the employee - and yes, I imagine anything above half an hour commute to seriously impede ones private life.

Comment: @Erik I had to drive mine for a week recently (cost and time very similar to the train).  Train is OK.  Comfortable, can work/read/play games on my phone.  Driving isn't fun. non-covid I've been known to camp in my van near work when the trains weren't running.  For an odd day I'd rather cycle 2-3 hours each way than drive 1-2, but not more than once a week.  But some people can sit in a car all day and not mind

Comment: No you are not being unreasonable, that sort of commute could very well impact your well being, even if its only 2 months. Commuting 100 miles a day to accomplish work that CAN be done remotely is ridiculous.

Comment: @Nathan, you really need to tell us which country or which state you're located in. And whether you're still on probation or not. And I know you told us what the offer letter stated, but you need to read your full contract to see if it doesn't contradict or doesn't try to supersede what's written in your offer letter. And the same goes for the employee manual should the manual be referred to in your contract.

Comment: how on earth are there an aggregate over 120 upvotes on answers to this question when we don't know where OP is working or in what industry?

Comment: How long would that commute take you, and what would be the cost?

Comment: "and is this something they can terminate me for?" How on earth do you expect this to be answered without a location?? You think all laws all the same everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. I’m working out the logistics with the higher-ups and luckily they’re not going to ask me to commute everyday; once a week at most. I have a strong work ethic and a determination to be a team player, but messing with someone’s commute two weeks into their employment feels like it’s crossing a line. For those of you asking, I am in corporate banking in Los Angeles.

Comment: Asker posted an answer (which is actually a comment) in which they mentioned the following: "I am in corporate banking in Los Angeles", in case someone with edit privilege wants to add it in.

Comment: @Nathan We have no idea where in the world you live. For example, I live in Japan. Some countries have laws that would require the company to subsidise or pay the commuting to your new location. In my native UK, I believe you could claim commuting to this new location as an expense, and most companies here in Japan would pay for commuting even from home to a permanent workplace. Beyond that, under UK law I believe you could potentially argue that the travelling distance is unreasonable. But is UK law relevant to you? Is Japanese law relevant to you?

Comment: what did your boss say when they asked?

Comment: regarding locations requests, the OP mentions the distance in miles, so that narrows it down to very few countries

Comment: @Llama do you measure distances in miles?

Comment: @njzk2 In the UK we do. In Japan it's kilometers.

Answer (score 112):

Ask for the commute to be part of your working hours or ask for overtime pay.

Comment: also ask for reimbursement for gas, 50 miles both ways is a pretty long hike.

Comment: I was seconded to work from an office around 50 miles from my home office for about 6 months.  During that time I was offered a hotel to stay at or the use of a company vehicle and time paid for the commute.  I took the car and money.  I was paid at overtime rates for the commute, a very lucrative arrangement.  This was in the UK.

Comment: *Or* ask for the commute to be part of your working hours, and arrive late / leave early...?

Comment: @Derek in the US, you're better off asking to be reimbursed at the IRS mileage rate. It's meant to cover fuel as well as wear & tear on the car and it's something most companies are easily set up to handle.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere: Entirely depends on the commute.  50 miles on Bay Area freeways?  No way are they going to pay enough.  50 miles on untrafficed mountain road?  I might pay them :-)

Comment: @alroc - Gas prices are quickly reaching a point where it will cost more than you are reimbursed at the IRS rate.  IRS rate won’t be changing anytime soon or even significantly since such a change is permanent even once gas prices decrease

Comment: @Donald  At 15 miles per gallon and $4.50 a gallon (higher than the average cost in California, the most expensive state), gas would cost 30 cents a mile.  [IRS reimbursement](https://www.irs.gov/tax-professionals/standard-mileage-rates) is 56 cents per mile, down from 58 in 2019.  At a more realistic 25 MPG and $3.25 per gallon (just above the US average), gas would be 13 cents a mile.  So incorrect about two things:  first, we're not close to gas costing more per mile than the IRS rate; second, the IRS rate can change, as it has every one of the last ten years.

Answer (score 55):

No, you are not being unreasonable for not wanting to have that extra commute imposed on you.

You were hired to work on Office A from X hour to Y. What should happen is that you go to work at Office A at X. Then, if they want you to be on Office B you would travel there *during your work hours*, and travel back from there so you can check out of local office at Y. This should be at company expense, you could be given a company car, travel with another employee that is also going from Office A to Office B, by public transport (paid by the company) or, if going in your own car, be reimbursed for that mileage in whatever way is stated by the company policies.

You "sell" to the company a number of hours of your time. If instead of doing your "expected" kind of work, they prefer to have you doing something else, like driving between offices, that shouldn't concern you.¹ Of course, the company will probably not like to lose those hours of your work every week on that "internal commute", so it will be in their interest to see if they can have you working remotely from the Office A. But if they find it so important that you are in Office B to have you start your working hours moving between offices, well, it's their choice.

¹ *In general*, obviously there are cases where it would matter, such as if the task they gave you was denigrating, if driving was a problem for you (or even didn't have a license!), etc.

Answer (score 15):

I think if they require you to work off-site, you can ask them if they can provide accommodation for you for that 2 months, eg. book a hotel room or Airbnb.

My example:
I work in the UK, and from time to time I'm being asked to support sites in other cities in the country, and the other company books me a hotel and car/transport ticket (if the site is more than 25 miles away).

Comment: In the UK, it only needs to be 2 miles from your normal place of work, for travel expenses etc - asking for accommodation just 2 miles away might be pushing it though,

Comment: @freedomn-m I once got given overnight hotel accommodation directly opposite my office because we had gone from North England to South Wales and back on my first day of work :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with much of what's already been said.  This answer is about proposing a compromise that can work well in some situations.

The mode of transport is important, as is the nature of the work.  If there's a fast train, and you can work on the train, then everyone should be happy with you doing the majority of the journey during normal working hours, working as you do so. I have seen this agreed to for a new starter, then vetoed by HR, and of course if you're a lab chemist or work on top secret material it's less likely to be possible.  The company should bear the cost as this is a secondment and not what you were recruited for.

This is an awkward distance though.  Much longer and they'd need to provide accommodation (a neighbour was put up in a hotel for a few nights a week at about 80 miles recently). Much shorter and many people would consider it if they can get a clear run. For example I have a 40-mile train journey and while this isn't part of my usual working hours, I do often do some work; my evening commute can be very useful for email exchanges with colleagues who keep later hours than me.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan, I have been working in Russia and the US. In both countries the employer is interested in using you for less money. You sell your time, your life and health. Employer gets your time, ideas, sweat and tear in exchange for money. You must establish personal boundries and requesting coverage for commute time is one of the basic things. Don't be afraid to stood up for yourself. Team player/work ethic etc - is a BS that is used to make sure that you are going to work up late till Sunday for free. Don't buy it. Remember, if you get into accident in your commute time - you are going to pay for it. If this happens during work hours your employer is going to pay for it. Now realize, that employer puts u under risk of getting injured in the car accident and ensures that you are going to be held responsible for it. Doesn't it make you feel foolish? If you will accept their terms, the following is going to happen: every other day there will be another important meeting or something will happen. You have to go there. In one month you will be going there every day for various reasons so. And you won't be able to back out because you'll be afraid to be fired and accepted rules of the game (again, team player all this stuff). It is better to disagree with the stuff now, renegotiate or find another place to work. Only you can protect yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can totally say no. However, people do remember who is flexible and who is not and use that knowledge when filling higher up positions that require flexibility.

So, you can do whatever you want, but it can hurt your career.

Comment: He's just starting, straight out of university. It's not like this is the job he'll want to keep for the rest of his life, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being unreasonable, but you'll want to be looking for a new job as soon as possible.  From your perspective, this company has a culture and expectations that you don't care for; why would you work there? From your employer's perspective, they got work to do and need people with a certain work ethic; why would they want to keep you around?

Comment: _Asking_ is basically the opposite of _expectations_.

Answer (score 0):

How badly do you need the job?  If you can get another suitable job within a tolerable amount of time, then realize you have the power.

And to answer your question, no, it is not reasonable to expect you to travel both ways on your dime.

In the USA, this would normally mean you'd be reimbursed "for mileage" which includes fuel and wear-and-tear on your vehicle.  It can also mean that the commute hours are counted as the work day.

If you say you won't commute, the managers involved would have to actually work to ensure you could work remotely from the local office. They are "solving" the logistical hassles by asking you to commute.  They probably also want you to absorb the cost, or haven't even thought about it. As one gets older and more established, a little gasoline doesn't factor very much into the financial equation. Starting out, however, every penny matters.